# How to ensure the platform controls all payouts for a connected Stripe account?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payout

I currently developed website that works as a marketplace for consulting. Students but multihour packages from consultants. The current workflow for is like this:

1. Students make payment for consultant packages and the payment intend directs them to the platform account.
2. When a session is completed as part of a package, a portion of the package will be transferred to Consultant’s connected stripe account through Transfer API right away. Payouts are currently daily.

I want to change the workflow to work with manual payout delays to prevent instant payouts and not use transfers as my platform account is not based in the US.

I would like to stop having consultants the ability to control their payouts.

Students on the site will make a payment using paymentintent API and money flows to the consultant’s stripe account minus the application fee

The payout API documentation that stripe provides does not explain how the platform can direct the manual payout on behalf of the connected account and how to stop my connected accounts from controlling the payouts themselves

I tried looking through the following links but they didn’t help:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/platform-controls-for-standard-accounts#configuring-platform-controls

Comment: This is largely dependent on the kind of [Connect accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) you would be onboarding. Are you using standard like the link you shared references?

Comment: @JonathanSteele yes I am using standard accounts! Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide

Comment: You should be creating accounts via the API and onboarding them using Account Links. That flow is outlined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts). When creating the Account, you can configure the [Payout schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manage-payout-schedule) by passing the [`settings[payouts][schedule]` hash](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-settings-payouts-schedule).

Comment: @JonathanSteele thank you for your help! I have worked on this but one thing I am still struggling is disabling manual payments for standard accounts. According to this link (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/platform-controls-for-standard-accounts): "Note: If you need full control over your connected accounts’ payouts and want to restrict your connected accounts from being able to make their own payouts, contact us with a detailed description of your use case." Do you have any experience with how Stripe actually restricts the connected standard accounts?

Comment: I do not I'm afraid. You should speak to the [support team](https://support.stirpe.com/contact) about that.